3D extension of the Principal part 1/x distribution
I'm wondering if  there is  a way  to define a distribution with the principal value of $$\frac{1}{r^3}=\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}$$ in analogy in $\mathbb{R}$ with the principal part of $\frac{1}{x}$, that "acts" in the following way: $$\langle \operatorname{P.V.}\frac{1}{x},\varphi\rangle=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}} \int_{\mathbb{R}-(-\epsilon,\epsilon)}\frac{\varphi(x)}{x} dx$$. However I have noticed that if $\varphi(\vec{0})\neq 0$, then $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0{+}}\int_{\mathbb{R^3}-B(\vec{0},\epsilon)}{} \frac{\phi(\vec{r})}{r^3} d^3r$$ diverges, so the previous definition is not of help. Is there any other possible definition? The problem arises from the problem of decomposing a vector field in a longitudinal and trasverse part according to the Helmholtz decomposition. In that case it pops out a term of this kind, in the process of building up the longitudinal and trasverse projection operators:$$T_{ij}(\vec{r},\vec{r'})=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i \partial x_j^{'}}\left(\frac{1}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r'}|}\right)=\frac{\delta_{ij}}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r'}|^3}-\frac{3(x_i-x_i^{'})(x_j-x_j^{'})}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r'}|^5}+\frac{4\pi}{3}\delta_{ij}\delta({\vec{r}-\vec{r'}}).$$ Here $\vec{r}=(x,y,z)$ and $\vec{r^{'}}=(x^{'},y^{'},z^{'})$ and i,j=1,2,3. After a traslation the first term in the sum on the right side becomes of the type 1/$r^3$, but the problem is how to interpret it. Many references say that it is to be interpreted as a principal value, but this seems to be incorrect. Maybe is to be interpreted according to the answer two in Principal value of 1/|x|?

If my sloppy calculation is correct then $f:=-(1+\ln r)/r \in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb R^3)$ satisfies
$\Delta f=\frac{1}{r^3}$
so you can define
$$
\langle \operatorname{pv}\frac{1}{r^3}, \varphi \rangle
= - \langle \frac{1+\ln r}{r}, \Delta\varphi \rangle.
$$
